# PrimeFaces did not load in Crud sample

Tags: jsf, netbeans, primefaces

I'm following this tutorial: www.youtube.com/watch?v=jgEItv9ZQN8‎

On NetBeans 7.3.1, GlassFish 3.2 and PrimeFaces 3.5

but when I run the application the default style of web page is crudcss.css not PrimeFaces.css. Even the Crud Pages don't have any PrimeFaces Look and Feel. in the first page there is a link to welcomPrimeFaces.xhtml but there is no Crud availability inside it.

Here is my index.html where I manually added prime ui link and script to head

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="primeui-0.9.6.css"/>        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="primeui-0.9.6.js"></script>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        Hello from Facelets

        <br />
        <h:link outcome="welcomePrimefaces" value="Primefaces welcome page" />
        <br />
        <h:link outcome="/manufacturer/List" value="Show All Manufacturer Items"/>
        <br />
        <h:link outcome="/product/List" value="Show All Product Items"/>
        <br />
        <h:link outcome="/productCode/List" value="Show All ProductCode Items"/>
    </h:body>



</html>
```

Comment: If your page doesn't have `<h:head>` tag then primefaces css cannot be included. Do you have that tag? Please, show us your .xhtml

Comment: Yes I already have the head and I manually added the prime ui link and style to it. I edited my post so you can see my index.xhtml

Comment: you don't need to add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="primeui-0.9.6.css"/>        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="primeui-0.9.6.js"></script>`. It is automattically added

Comment: but the only link that was added to my page was css/jsfcrud.css

Comment: Any ways, finally I found the solution. I had to insall this plugin first. http://sourceforge.net/projects/nbpfcrudgen/